# How to use C++ regex to find characters between square brackets

Tags: c++, regex

I have a C++ regex to search for characters inside square brackets, for instance if the string is x[7:0], I want to return 7:0. This is what my regex looks like -

```
std::regex reg("\[(.*?)\]");
```

When I compile (g++) I get the following warning -

../fixedPointFormatter.cc:30:18: warning: unknown escape sequence: ']'
std::regex reg("[(.*?)]");
^~~~~~~~~~~

The following returns nothing...

```
if (regex_search(arg, matches, reg)) {
 for (int i=1; i<matches.size(); i++) {
   cout << matches[i] << endl;
 }
}
```

Can someone help identify what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex needs the `[` and the `]` to be escaped using `\`. However, to provide that to the regex, you need to escape the `\`s in the string.

```
std::regex reg("\\[(.*?)\\]");
```

Comment: You are welcome, @RajatMitra. Glad I was able to help.